# XamlParseException while trying to bind Date of Windows 10 CalendarDatePicker

Tags: xaml, mvvm, data-binding, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am trying to bind the Date attribute of the **CalendarDatePicker** with a DateTime property in a Windows 10 Universal App:

```
<CalendarDatePicker
    Date="{Binding ClientDetailsViewModel.BirthDate,
    Converter={StaticResource DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter} }"
    Foreground="{StaticResource TextGreyBrush}"  />
```

I am getting the following exception while the view initializes:

> An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'
>   occurred in KLMMobile.UI.exe but was not handled in user code
>
> WinRT information: Failed to assign to property
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.CalendarDatePicker.Date'. [Line: 93
>   Position: 41]

I've tested it with the **DatePicker** and it worked perfectly.

Comment: CalendarDatePicker.Date is `Nullable<DateTimeOffset>` whereas DatePicker.Date is `DateTimeOffset`.  It shouldn't matter, normally, but the binding may not consider implicit castability when comparing types during a binding (or something :/). Change your DateTimeToDateTimeOffsetConverter to return a nullable DateTimeOffset, or create a new version that does, and see if it helps.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Actually it doesn't reach the converter. In fact even if I set the Date in back code TestCalendarDatePicker.Date = DateTimeOffset.Now; it doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of effort trying to bind the Date, I overcame this problem by using a trigger for DateChanged and binding the PlaceHolderText with the Property that should be displayed at start.

```
<CalendarDatePicker 
                 PlaceholderText="{Binding UpdateWorkingTimeModel.StartTime, Converter={StaticResource TicksToDateTimeConverter}, ConverterParameter='dd.MM.yyyy', Mode=TwoWay}">
                    <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="DateChanged">
                            <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DatePickedCommand}"/>
                        </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                    </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                </CalendarDatePicker>
```